# Http Module Setup on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I had developed Generic blacklist and whitelist filter that reduces XSS/SQLi risks for ASP applications.
I used C#, .NET 3.5

So, I built it as dll, signed, added to GAC and can use it in a single website, by inserting in web.config

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="RequestScanner" type="IISRequestScanner.RequestScanner, IISRequestScanner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a629be8f1e2f2c9"/>
</httpModules>
```

But I want to use this module for all sites, so it should be integrated to IIS. 
I tried to add it to IIS as managed module, via mappers, no results?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing the machine.config file instead of the web.config.  The file can be found at <windows>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\config\machine.config

Comment: Thanks for an answer, that really works but only for ASP.NET applications. I want make it working for all classic ASP sites that are located on IIS

Comment: Do not forget the Framework64 folder if you're on a 64-bit OS and have 64-bit or AnyCPU modules.